# how to append to json file in java

Tags: java, json

I have this js.json file

i want to add another block to the file.

**the file now ->**

```
[
{
"diff":"Easy",
"qus":"John1"
}
]
```

**how i want it to be ->**

```
[
{
"diff":"Easy",
"qus":"John1"
},
{
"diff":"Avg",
"qus":"John2"
}
]
```

Comment: Where's your problem, what did you try? Remember that this is not a place to do other people's work.

Comment: you could use a library, like Jackson, and convert it.. add your stuff and stringify back. one way..

Comment: Is your issue solved... ? please update

Comment: can you please upvote or accept my answer, if it helped you... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.json` library as follow:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr); //from the file
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(yourNewlyJsonObject);
jsonarray.put(jsonobject);
System.out.println(jsonarray.toString()); // or write it back to the file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this code.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject({
    "diff":"Avg",
    "qus":"John2"
    }); 


JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\exer4-courses.json"));   // reading the file and creating a json array of it.

a.put(obj);   // adding your created object into the array


// writing the JSONObject into a file(info.json)
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:\\exer4-courses.json");         // writing back to the file
            fileWriter.write(a.toJSONString());
            fileWriter.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

References:

https://www.javatpoint.com/json-tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaIO/article.html

Comment: `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` do not exist in the java API, you should probably say where they come from

Comment: check the URLs shared in the answer.